# R ggplot2: Why do I get the error "Error in f(..., self = self) : attempt to apply non-function"?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to test out the [`ggbeeswarm`](https://github.com/eclarke/ggbeeswarm) package.

Unfortunately, I get an error when I run the commands below.
Why do I get this error?

```
R version 3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336) -- "Very Secure Dishes"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> require(ggbeeswarm)
Loading required package: ggbeeswarm
Loading required package: ggplot2
Warning messages:
1: package ‘ggbeeswarm’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
2: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
> ggplot(iris,aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + geom_quasirandom()
Error in f(..., self = self) : attempt to apply non-function
```

Comment: I can run the code under R 3.3.3. Perhaps you can update your R to the latest version.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error in R 3.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to update R to 3.2.5 or higher. Had that error in the past.

Comment: Indeed, after installing R version 3.3.3, I was able to run the code successfully.